# Laravel model mock

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking, mockery

I am trying to mock a model and return false on insert so i can test failure case.

here is my test mocking

```
$mockModel = Mockery::mock(\App\Models\MyModel::class)->shouldReceive(['insertGetId'])->once()->andReturn(false);
```

and here is my insert method in controller

```
$result = MyModel::insertGetId(['something' => 'somevalue',]);
dd($result);
```

and i am expecting $result to be false but instead i get the id (int).

if i remove dd(); i get this error on the terminal.

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method insertGetId() from Mockery_0_App_Models_MyModel should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **insertGetId()** which returns the inserted id. Use **insert()** instead.

If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use the insertGetId method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID like:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

but in case of insert it return true or false based on success or failure of query.

Comment: thanks but still i get true. mockery should have intercepted and returned false instead.

Comment: also if i use insert then how would i get last insertid?

Comment: You can put a check like if return value is 0 ie false, and if inserted successfully than it will return the id which is definitely greater than 0

Comment: it is always greater than 0, the Mockery::mock is not working.

Comment: also if i remove dd() i get this Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method insertGetId() from Mockery_0_App_Models_MyModel should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.